# Different browserlist for dev and prod?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to activate [Differential Loading](https://dev.to/lacolaco/differential-loading-a-new-feature-of-angular-cli-v8-4jl) only in production builds.
The reason is that I don't want dev build to take too long.

Since Differential loading is derived from browserlist content, **I'd like to configure different browserlist for each build**.

This is the browserlist for dev:

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
not IE 9-11
```

And this for prod:

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
not IE 9-11
```

I activate my dev and prod build with those commands:

dev: `ng build`

prod: `ng build --prod`

Pretty standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then changing the build config in your `angular.json` should do the trick. You can just copy what Angular does by default with the `environment.ts` file.

So under `build.configurations.production` in `angular.json` you can add to the `fileReplacements` array:

```
"fileReplacements": [
   {
     "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
     "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
   },
   {
     "replace": "src/.browserslistrc",
     "with": "src/.browserslistrc.prod"
   }
],
```

Those file names are assumed, but you can obviously substitute with whatever you need.

**Edit**

I'm  not entirely sure if that works or how to test it. According to the browserslist docs you can also use environment flags https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#configuring-for-different-environments

For Angular what this looks like is the following:

```
[development]
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
not IE 9-11

[production]
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
not IE 9-11
```

This should work using the `NODE_ENV` which Angular sets as `development` when using `ng serve` (as well as `ng build`) and `production` when using `ng build --prod`

Comment: In Angular 12 wnen I call `ng build --configuration production` I get an error ` Data path "/fileReplacements/1/replace" must match pattern "\.(([cm]?j|t)sx?|json)$".`

Comment: Yes, this does not seem to work anymore.